# Transparent blurred background to Canvas

Tags: wpf, transparency, blur

No idea how to create transparent blurred background to canvas **without bluring the canvas childrens** too.

This is the result I want - Blur the background but not the content:
[image]

Comment: Only one simple way is to use a texture which is something like blur and add opacity to it. In any other case you would have quite a performance killer if try to apply such effect for control tree.

Comment: can you add a sample of code so I can see if its good for me?

Comment: @StavAlfi Post your XAML.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## My Excuse

Pardon my inexperience with Stackoverflow but I thought I would try and help you out a little.

I didn't make this code, however seen as how this code isn't readily available to most people, here it is:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;

namespace BlurBehindDemo
{
internal enum AccentState
{
    ACCENT_DISABLED = 1,
    ACCENT_ENABLE_GRADIENT = 0,
    ACCENT_ENABLE_TRANSPARENTGRADIENT = 2,
    ACCENT_ENABLE_BLURBEHIND = 3,
    ACCENT_INVALID_STATE = 4
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct AccentPolicy
{
    public AccentState AccentState;
    public int AccentFlags;
    public int GradientColor;
    public int AnimationId;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct WindowCompositionAttributeData
{
    public WindowCompositionAttribute Attribute;
    public IntPtr Data;
    public int SizeOfData;
}

internal enum WindowCompositionAttribute
{
    // ...
    WCA_ACCENT_POLICY = 19
    // ...
}

/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern int SetWindowCompositionAttribute(IntPtr hwnd, ref WindowCompositionAttributeData data);

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        EnableBlur();
    }

    internal void EnableBlur()
    {
        var windowHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);

        var accent = new AccentPolicy();
        accent.AccentState = AccentState.ACCENT_ENABLE_BLURBEHIND;

        var accentStructSize = Marshal.SizeOf(accent);

        var accentPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(accentStructSize);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(accent, accentPtr, false);

        var data = new WindowCompositionAttributeData();
        data.Attribute = WindowCompositionAttribute.WCA_ACCENT_POLICY;
        data.SizeOfData = accentStructSize;
        data.Data = accentPtr;

        SetWindowCompositionAttribute(windowHelper.Handle, ref data);

        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(accentPtr);
    }

    private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DragMove();
    }
}
```

}

## Result

Once implemented, this will effect the whole Window as shown:

[image: Whole window is blurred]

### After a little tweaking

[image: Final Window]

## XAML

This was a project I made a few months back, so it won't look the same as yours, but with some tweaking you could easily make it into whatever you want it to be. The XAML of my design is as follows:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="MainWindow"
    Title="Blurred Opacity" Height="623" Width="752"
    Background="#727A7A7A"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    WindowStyle="None"
    BorderThickness="1"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded" MouseLeftButtonDown="Window_MouseDown" Topmost="True" BorderBrush="#FF1E9EC5">
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Fill="#FF0143A4" Height="130" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="White" Margin="0,130,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="375"/>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,130,0,0" Width="375">
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Height="50" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Category 1" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition" FontSize="35" Padding="10,0,0,0" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" LineHeight="6"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_Copy" Height="50" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Category 2" FontSize="35" Padding="10,0,0,0" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" LineHeight="6" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_Copy1" Height="50" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Category 3" FontSize="35" Padding="10,0,0,0" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" LineHeight="6" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_Copy2" Height="50" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Category 4" FontSize="35" Padding="10,0,0,0" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" LineHeight="6" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_Copy3" Height="50" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Category 5" FontSize="35" Padding="10,0,0,0" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" LineHeight="6" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_Copy4" Height="50" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Category 6" FontSize="35" Padding="10,0,0,0" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" LineHeight="6" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_Copy5" Height="50" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Category 7" FontSize="35" Padding="10,0,0,0" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" LineHeight="6" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_Copy6" Height="50" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Category 8" FontSize="35" Padding="10,0,0,0" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" LineHeight="6" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_Copy7" Height="90" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Example" FontSize="65" Padding="10,0,0,0" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" LineHeight="6" Margin="222.5,23,152.5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White"/>
    <Path Data="M705,27.333333 L735.66667,10" Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="24" Margin="0,7,21,0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="24" StrokeThickness="3" Stroke="White"/>
    <Path Data="M705,27.333333 L735.66667,10" Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="24.083" Margin="0,6.833,20.333,0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="24.167" StrokeThickness="3" Stroke="White" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Path.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Path.RenderTransform>
    </Path>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,130,0,0" Width="375">
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Height="50" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Item 1" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition" FontSize="35" Padding="10,0,0,0" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" LineHeight="6"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_Copy8" Height="50" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Item 2" FontSize="35" Padding="10,0,0,0" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" LineHeight="6" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_Copy9" Height="50" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="35" Padding="10,0,0,0" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" LineHeight="6" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition"><Run Text="Item "/><Run Text="3"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="3"/></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_Copy10" Height="50" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="35" Padding="10,0,0,0" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" LineHeight="6" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition"><Run Text="Item "/><Run Text="4"/></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_Copy11" Height="50" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="35" Padding="10,0,0,0" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" LineHeight="6" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition"><Run Text="Item "/><Run Text="5"/></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_Copy12" Height="50" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="35" Padding="10,0,0,0" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" LineHeight="6" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition"><Run Text="Item "/><Run Text="6"/></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_Copy13" Height="50" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="35" Padding="10,0,0,0" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" LineHeight="6" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition"><Run Text="Item "/><Run Text="7"/></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_Copy14" Height="50" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="35" Padding="10,0,0,0" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" LineHeight="6" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition"><Run Text="Item "/><Run Text="8"/></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_Copy15" Height="50" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="35" Padding="10,0,0,0" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" LineHeight="6" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition"><Run Text="Item "/><Run Text="9"/></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This was excatly what I was looking for. You should of post that 1 year ago when it was relevant :D Thanks anyway!

Comment: Hahaha no problem, to be fair I just joined a few days ago

Comment: THANK YOU. A sample that *ACTUALLY* works without a bunch of weird glitches. FINALLY. Other examples and GitHub samples all have weird jumpy glitches on start up.

Comment: @FraserMuir Is there any way to adjust the amount of blur?

Comment: @SledgeHammer Yup, I had the same! I was fighting rendering glitches. The fix is to set `AllowsTransparency="True"` on the window! I was trying to work around this with flicking `Opacity` and whatnot, but this is actually a stable fix.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that items inside a grid are layout on on top of the other:

```
<Grid >
    <Image Source="texture-7.jpg" Stretch="Fill" >
        <Image.Effect>
            <BlurEffect Radius="100"/>
        </Image.Effect>
    </Image>
    <Canvas Background="Transparent">
        <!-- Content -->
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

where "texture-7.jpg" is some image of a texture. if you also want it to be transparent simply set the opacity property of the Image

Comment: @StavAlfi What I ment is take the code you linked to and place it instead of the Canvas names "Blured background"

Comment: the above example doesnt blur transparent background at all

Comment: @StavAlfi Amit gave you an approach to achieving what you need ..
calling it "BlurCanvas" does nothing of course it was an hint

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
    <Canvas  Height="300" Width="300">
    <Canvas.Background>
        <VisualBrush Stretch="None">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Canvas Background="LightBlue" Height="300" Width="300">
                    <Canvas.Effect>
                        <BlurEffect Radius="150"></BlurEffect>
                    </Canvas.Effect>
                </Canvas>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Canvas.Background>
    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Height="50" Width="50"></Rectangle>
    <Rectangle Fill="Green" Margin="50" Height="50" Width="50"></Rectangle>
</Canvas>
```

[image]

Comment: your example only hide the background but not blur it. i gave an example please look. thanks anyway bro

Comment: your blue background isnt transperent.. only in its sides it get the result i want.

Comment: If you want inside background transparent then increase Radius in Blureffect.I have defined only 150.

Answer (score 0):

When using Windows10, please have a look at [BlurryControls](https://github.com/ConfusedHorse/BlurryControls). It provides a blurry window you can directly inherit from.

For Windows8 there is no solution to blur a Window (to my knowledge).

For Windows7/Vista a user called Ciantic provided the following solution: [Windows Aero Glass](http://ciantic.blogspot.de/2009/10/wpf-window-with-areo-glass-background-c.html). A working sample solution can be found here: [GlassingExtension](https://github.com/talestra/tov/blob/master/TalesOfVesperiaUtils/TalesOfVesperiaFrontendWPF/GlassingExtension.cs).

I hope this answers your question. Please respond if you have a question or suggestions to the solution targeting Windows10.