# WPF Rounded window corners with semitransparent blurred background still blur even with window transparent

Tags: wpf

I want rounded window corners (more specifically, only on the top two),
however my [window background is semitransparent blurred of whatever is behind it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28040646/transparent-blurred-background-to-canvas), and I'm trying to use the usual method of having a round corner border, which works, but the window, even though transparent, still gives off a blur effect.

Here's what's happening (showing one corner)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to set WindowStyle to WindowStyle.None, which will remove the chrome, then you can allow transparency which is an attribute int the Window element, and set the background color to transparent. All of this can be done as attributes to the window tag.

`WindowStyle="None"
AllowsTransparency="True"
Background="Transparent"`
To make the corners rounded, use a border and set the cornerRadius property

Comment: I can't have the window transparent because I need it to blur whatever it's behind.

Comment: I send you a link ..i hop this can helps you..https://github.com/riverar/sample-win10-aeroglass

Comment: It works for the most part, I forgot how good WPF is with handling transparency. See my updated question, it still blurs to the normal shape/size of the window. A way to apply the blur effect to the border rather than the whole window would probably fix the issue.